# How to make jOOQ generate array['foo'] instead of ?::varchar[]

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

jOOQ generate following SQL code:

```
("table"."column" @> ?::varchar[])
```

from following Java code:

```
DSL.condition("{0} @> {1}", field, array);
```

The problem is that PostgreSQL complains with following error:

```
operator does not exist: character[] @> character varying[]
```

The column is of type `char[3]`.

I tried to cast the array:

```
DSL.condition("{0} @> {1}", field, DSL.cast(array, field.getDataType())));
```

and it generates:

```
("table"."column" @> cast(?::varchar[] as char[]))
```

Unfortunately, PostgreSQL doesn't like that casting and returns nothing. I tried to do it manually and when I removed all those castings, it worked.

How do I ask jOOQ to generate something like `array['foo', 'bar']` or anything that can be used in a prepared statement without the explicit cast?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DSL.val(array, field.getDataType())`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#val(java.lang.Object,org.jooq.DataType)) to explicitly set the data type for a bind value. For example:

```java
System.out.println(ctx.render(
    DSL.val(new String[] {"a", "b"}, SQLDataType.CHAR(1).getArrayDataType())
));
```

Renders `?::char(1)[]`

Comment: Using the `DSL.condition("", DSL.val(array, type))` alone seems correct based on the output of its toString(). But, once I put it in the complete select expression, it's back to `?::varchar[]`

Comment: @IrsyadAsyhariLubis: I've updated my answer. It seems to work correctly when generating bind parameters, but not when inlining: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11441. Perhaps you ran into a bug. Feel free to report one with instructions on how to reproduce the exact behaviour you're seeing: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose